# Spring @Secured method is not working when called through a filter that uses a Flying Saucer (Itext) ReplacedElementFactory implementation

Tags: spring, security, authentication, filter, itext

When I call a Spring @Secured method that is found on a @Service class, through a normal @Controller class, the authentication is working correctly.

When I call the same method through an IText PDF filter, using a org.xhtmlrenderer.extend.ReplacedElementFactory implementation, I get the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:325)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
```

The security is obviously working because users without the required roles receive an Access Denied Exception, while other users with the correct roles have no issues at all.

Here is a snippet from my web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>pdfFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>pdfFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/reports/pdf/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is a snippet of the ReplacedElementFactory implementation:

```
@Inject private ImageService imageService;

    @Override
    public ReplacedElement createReplacedElement(LayoutContext ctx, BlockBox box, UserAgentCallback uac, int width, int height) {

        Element el = box.getElement();
        if (el == null) {
            return null; 
        }

        String nodeName =  el.getNodeName();
        if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {
            String srcAttr = el.getAttribute("src");
            FSImage fsImage;
            try {
                fsImage = getImage(srcAttr, uac);
            }catch(BadElementException ex) {
                fsImage = null;
            }catch(IOException ex) {
                fsImage = null;
            }catch(NullPointerException ex) {
                fsImage = null;
            }

            if (fsImage != null) {
                if (width != -1 || height != -1) {
                    fsImage.scale(width, height);
                }

                return new ITextImageElement(fsImage);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

private FSImage getImage(String src, UserAgentCallback uac) throws IOException, BadElementException, NullPointerException {
        FSImage fsImage;

        String[] split = src.split("/");
        if (src.contains("image/person/")) {                
            Long id = Long.valueOf( split[split.length - 1] );
            Image img = imageService.getPersonImageByImageId(id);           
            fsImage = new ITextFSImage(com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(img.getImage()));

        return fsImage;
    }
```

Here is my ImageService class method:

```
@Secured({"ROLE_MY_ROLE_READ"})
    public Image getPersonImageByImageId(Long imageId) {
        return imageDao.findOne(imageId);
    }
```

The failure happens on the call to the image service method, assumably because it is Secured and the ReplacedElementFactory implementation does not have access to the security context, but how do I authenticate?

I am new to posting, so please let me know if there is anything else required.

Comment: For now, I just created a second non-secured method that is only called in the ReplacedElementFactory implementation. I don't like this solution, however the URL also has some security, so it isn't totally insecure. I just want a better answer than my current solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have configured your security to kick in. but if you have used for that also then check the ordering of the filter. The security filter should be before your pdffilter.

Comment: I have edited the question and data to more accurately reflect the issue.